# Why doesn't this work? (ProjectEulerProblem5)

Tags: java

I'm trying our Project Euler and I've gotten to Problem 5 and this is the question:

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

This is what I've come up with:

```
for (int x = 1; x >= 100100100; x++) { //100100100 is just a number to count to, an end point.
    int count = 0;
    for (int b = 1; b <= 20; b++) {
        if (x % b == 0) { //Tests numbers.
            count++; //Counter

            if (count == 20) { //Numbers that fit between 1 and 100100100
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this it does not print a value. What have I done wrong/overlooked?

Comment: Shouldn't for condition be `x <= ...`? Because x is initialised as 1, so it doesn't even enter the body of the loop at all.

Comment: Hint: instead of using `x++` you might take steps of `20` :)

Comment: When is x == 1 and x >= 100100100 at the same time?

Comment: Why should I use steps of 20? Just curious.

Comment: You'll need to go further than 100100100.  The correct answer is bigger than this.

Comment: @Heavypick The number you're searching for needs to be divisible by `20`. Now think a bit about your loop. Is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 19` divisible by `20`? The same goes for `21, ..., 39`, you will basically skip a lot of iterations that obviously won't lead to the answer

Comment: @HamZa But `x` also has to be initialised at 20 then? Otherwise, any other value, if you add 20, will never be divisable by 20.

Comment: @AntonH If I spill all the beans I will ruin the fun

Comment: You can also do this by computing the multisets of prime factors of #'s from 1 to 20, taking the union of these multisets, then multiplying these numbers: union({2}{3}{2,2}{5}{3,2}{7}{2,2,2}{3,3}{5,2}{11}{3,2,2}{13}{7,2}{3,5}{2,2,2,2}{17}{3,3,2}{19}{2,2,5})={2,2,2,2,3,3,5,7,11,13,17,19}. So try `System.out.println(2*2*2*2*3*3*5*7*11*13*17*19);`.

Comment: I got the answer. I just had to change the sign and also increase the size of the number, then I took the idea of adding 20 instead of 1 to each cycle and found it even faster. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the loop from:

```
for (int x = 1; x >= 100100100; x++) {
```

to:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 100100100; x++) {
```

As it is, you're not even entering the body of the loop, since you don't verify the condition after initialising the values.

Comment: This won't work, as the correct answer is larger than 100100100.

Comment: My answer was concerning his loop condition, rather than the actual value that has was using as a max value (he could use `Integer.MAX_VALUE instead`). But yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

First of  all what the question is really asking for is that finding the smallest number which is evenly divisible byall of the numbers from 1 to 20. Which means you do not need to deal with another number in your code 100100100. All you need to do is finding the biggest powers of all the prime numbers which is in the range.In which case it would be

2^4*3^2*5*7*11*13*17

.

Answer (score 0):

Your maximum is took small.  You need to solve you problem differently as brute force will take too long (as indeed most project euler tasks do) This is because most of them are mathematical challenges not really programming challenges.

What you need to do it to work out the factors this number will have.

```
2 => must be a multiple of 2
3 => must also be a multiple of 3
4 => must be a multiple of 2 and 2
5 => must be a multiple of 5
6 = > must be a multiple of 2 and 3
```

From 2 to 6 you need 2*2 * 3 * 5 is the smallest factors will satisfy all of these or 60.  For 2 to 20 you need to consider them all.  Note: it will be a multiple of 7, 11, 13 ,17 and 19.  Once you find how many factors of each you need,

Comment: @DavidWallace Thank you, just googled the answer ;)

Comment: Googled it?  I just typed `16 x 9 x 5 x 7 x 11 x 13 x 17 x 19 =` into a calculator.

Comment: @DavidWallace I used cut-n-paste of aliatlii's answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an answer to your question, since it has been answered, but my input:

You should do something like this:

```
boolean flag = true;
if(x % b !=0){        // If one number does not meet the condition
    flag = false;     // A flag tells you the test failed
}
```

instead of counting through every item. And a `while` loop to count to infinity.

Also, SOLUTION SPOILER ALERT: For the solution of the problem, my approach would be using prime numbers and something called prime factorization.